# How to forEach in Elixir

Tags: javascript, foreach, elixir

How do you forEach in Elixir? In JavaScript (and most languages have an equivalent), I can iterate through the various items in a list and do something with side effects like outputting to the console.

```
[1,2,3].forEach(function(num) {
    console.log(num);
});

//=> 1
//=> 2
//=> 3
```

Is there an equivalent in elixir?

Comment: `for`? http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/comprehensions.html

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Iterating through a collection is most often handled with the `Enum` module.  [`Enum.each/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#each/2) is what you're looking for if you want to generate side effects.

`Enum.each/2` function takes two arguments: your collection and a function to run on every member of the collection.

Like so:

```
iex(3)> Enum.each([1, 2, 3], fn x -> IO.puts x end)
1
2
3
:ok
```

I wrote a [blog post](https://www.stridenyc.com/blog/ruby-vs-elixir-each) about this recently which goes into more details. The post is a comparison between Elixir and Ruby, but the same exact logic applies to JavaScript.

Answer (score 18):

One option would be to use comprehensions:

```
for item <- items do
  IO.inspect(item)
end
```

Another option is to enumerate:

```
Enum.each items, fn(item) ->
  IO.inspect(item)
end
```

Answer (score 8):

Another option would be to use [`Enum.map/2`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Enum.html#map/2). `Enum.each/2` always returns `:ok`, while `map/2` iterates over the list and returns new values (equivalent to Javascript's `Array.map`)

```
iex(3)> Enum.map([1, 2, 3], fn x -> x * x end)
[1, 4, 9]
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use `foreach` specifically, you could use Erlang's `foreach/2`:

```
 :lists.foreach(fn a -> IO.puts a + a end, [1,2,3])
 # 2
 # 4
 # 6
```